# Twitter4j: Get list of replies for a certain tweet

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

Is it possible to get a list of tweets that reply to a tweet (or to its replies) using twitter4j?
The twitter website and Android app have this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code I'm using in [welshare](http://welshare.com)

The first part gets all the tweets that twitter is displaying below the tweet, when it is opened. The rest takes care of conversations, in case the tweet is a reply to some other tweet.

```
RelatedResults results = t.getRelatedResults(tweetId);
List<Status> conversations = results.getTweetsWithConversation();
/////////
Status originalStatus = t.showStatus(tweetId);
if (conversations.isEmpty()) {
    conversations = results.getTweetsWithReply();
}

if (conversations.isEmpty()) {
    conversations = new ArrayList<Status>();
    Status status = originalStatus;
    while (status.getInReplyToStatusId() > 0) {
        status = t.showStatus(status.getInReplyToStatusId());
        conversations.add(status);
    }
}
// show the current message in the conversation, if there's such
if (!conversations.isEmpty()) {
    conversations.add(originalStatus);
}
```

EDIT: This wont work anymore as Twitter API v 1 is now not in use

Comment: What is "t" here ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `InReplyToStatusId` field value using `Status.getInReplyToStatusId()`

Use the code code below recursively to get all replies or conversations of a tweet using API v1.1:

```
Status replyStatus = twitter.showStatus(status.getInReplyToStatusId());
System.out.println(replyStatus.getText())
```

Using this I could pull Tweets with all of their replies.

Comment: could you plz provide a sample code showing the use of it and the flow?

Comment: @Hari, it has been long time, but do you have a complete code. I need to get all replies to a specific tweet ( 2 year old tweet). Thanks

Comment: I tried it, but didn't got the replies, (I am using Twitter4j 4.0.4 version). Could you pls share the reference code ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the way to do this in https://github.com/klinker24/Talon-for-Twitter and modified it a little

```
public ArrayList<Status> getDiscussion(Status status, Twitter twitter) {
    ArrayList<Status> replies = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Status> all = null;

    try {
        long id = status.getId();
        String screenname = status.getUser().getScreenName();

        Query query = new Query("@" + screenname + " since_id:" + id);

        System.out.println("query string: " + query.getQuery());

        try {
            query.setCount(100);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // enlarge buffer error?
            query.setCount(30);
        }

        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        System.out.println("result: " + result.getTweets().size());

        all = new ArrayList<Status>();

        do {
            System.out.println("do loop repetition");

            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

            for (Status tweet : tweets)
                if (tweet.getInReplyToStatusId() == id)
                    all.add(tweet);

            if (all.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = all.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    replies.add(all.get(i));
                all.clear();
            }

            query = result.nextQuery();

            if (query != null)
                result = twitter.search(query);

        } while (query != null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return replies;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use "@" before screen name. It searches only other people mentioning the account. To search replies to the tweet from the account, use "to:". See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search for query operators.

```
public ArrayList<Status> getReplies(String screenName, long tweetID) {
    ArrayList<Status> replies = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Query query = new Query("to:" + screenName + " since_id:" + tweetID);
        QueryResult results;

        do {
            results = twitter.search(query);
            System.out.println("Results: " + results.getTweets().size());
            List<Status> tweets = results.getTweets();

            for (Status tweet : tweets) 
                if (tweet.getInReplyToStatusId() == tweetID)
                    replies.add(tweet);
        } while ((query = results.nextQuery()) != null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return replies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API does not have a function for getting replies of a tweet but you can achieve it with several steps. Here is the most efficient way for Twitter API version 7.0.

---

**Step 1 -** Get all replies. (This function can only return up to 800 most recent replies)

```
List<Status> replyList = twitter.getMentionsTimeline(new Paging(1, 800));
```

---

**Step 2 -** If a user replies to his own tweet, these replies are returned to `getUserTimeline()` instead of `getMentionsTimeline()`. Thus, you need to move these replies to the right place.

```
List<Status> tweetList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Status tweet : twitter.getUserTimeline()) {
    if (tweet.getInReplyToStatusId() == -1) {
        tweetList.add(tweet);
    } else {
        replyList.add(tweet);
    }
}
```

---

**Step 3 -** Use `getInReplyToStatusId()` to identify the original tweet of each reply. Make your function recursive (as shown below) if you want to get the nested replies as well.

```
public void getReply(Status tweet) {
    for (Status reply : replyList) {
        if (tweet.getId() == reply.getInReplyToStatusId()) {
            System.out.println(reply.getText());
            getReply(reply);
        }
    }
}
```