# Twitter4j, replies to a tweet

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

Can someone please provide me a method to gel all replies to a given status using Twitter4j? 
I've searched a lot but all I could find is this[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969896/twitter4j-get-list-of-replies-for-a-certain-tweet) but I'm not able to use it.

This simply tells me that given a status A I can get the status B if A is a reply to B.
But what if I only have B?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a year old now, I've stumbled on it while having developed a solution requested over here:

You need to grab users timelines and users mentions

```
 TwitterInstance.getUserTimeline(pageno);
 TwitterInstance.getMentionsTimeline(pageno);
```

and store returned status' in an Arraylist.

```
  ArrayList<twitter4j.Status> statusList= new ArrayList<twitter4j.Status>();
```

Then you may search for you `B` from above and with that you can iterate through the status list with `id` and `inReplyTo`, building up the tree in memory.