# Get List of replys

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j for getting tweets for specific account on twitter `

```
try {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
        Paging page = new Paging(1,100);
        List<Status> status = twitter.getUserTimeline("BarackObama",page);
        if (status != null){
            for (Status statuses : status) {
                System.out.println("@" + statuses.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + statuses.getText());}} catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }`
```

Now how i can list of replys for each status (tweet) i have got?????
I have tried `statuses.getInReplyToStatusId()` but i got nothing 
please help me

Comment: Replay =  reply ? Status = tweet?

Comment: yes that's what i mean

Comment: If 'getInReplyToStatusId()' returns nothing, there aren't any replies. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ivamluz/6284531) you can find some related code snippets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969896/twitter4j-get-list-of-replies-for-a-certain-tweet

Comment: I am sure there is replies on these tweet but i get nothing from  getInReplyToStatusId() :(