# How to get a retweet text message using Twitter4j library

Tags: java, twitter, message, twitter4j, gettext

I am new to Twitter4j library. I need to get all the retweets of a tweet. To do this I have written this java code:

```
try {
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(Long.parseLong(id));
    System.out.println(statuses.size());

    for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.get);
    }
} catch{
    some code...
}
```

`tf` is a variable I declared as

```
tf = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
```

and includes the information about the configuration. When I run the code the output I get is

```
@rssmiranda - RT @repubblicait: Tokyo, una corona per Edymar: è la miss   delle miss
```

As you can see we have on the left the info about the user but on the right we have the message of the general tweet, not the message included in the retweet written by the user. 
How can I display the retweet written by (for example) @rssmiranda? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Your System.out.println line is broken. Could you provide the entire line please?

Comment: What do you mean Bruno Silva? All I'd like to do is to get retweets' texts such as "Buat masa sekarang gua adalah playground aku"

see this picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwz2ebllnt9apj0/Cattura.PNG?dl=0

Comment: are you looking for the comment on the retweet? or what?

Comment: Yes @MounirElfassi, i am looking for the text written by the users in their retweets, look at this picture. I need to get the messages inside the red boxes...https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwz2ebllnt9apj0/Cattura.PNG?dl=0

Comment: check this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/32173317/2494799

Comment: thanks Mounir for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

For showing number of retweet:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=<id>
```

It will give you the answer like -

"retweet_count": 1 etc.

For all the details of retweet read this :[GET statuses/retweets/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid)